# Upload file using curl put - multipart/form-data

Tags: php, curl, put

I am trying to upload document via curl-put method. But when I call this file its just generate 0 byte file not uploading file.

I am consuming third party's web service.

What is missing here ?Is there something in header ?
In file-name do we need to pass file-name or path ?

PHP Code

```
        $data = json_encode($this->data);
        $file_url = $filepath;
        $f = array($filepath);

        $eol = "\r\n";
        $BOUNDARY = md5(time());
        $BODY=""; //init my curl body
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY. $eol; //start param header
        $BODY .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Appointment"' . $eol . $eol; // last Content with 2 $eol, in this case is only 1 content.           
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY. $eol; // start 2nd param,
        $BODY.= 'Content-Disposition: form-data;  filename='.$filepath. $eol ; //first Content data for post file, remember you only put 1 when you are going to add more Contents, and 2 on the last, to close the Content Instance
        $BODY.= 'Content-Type: application/pdf' . $eol; //Same before row      
        $BODY.= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_url))) . $eol; // we write the Base64 File Content and the $eol to finish the data,
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY .'--' . $eol. $eol; // we close the param and the post width "--" and 2 $eol at the end of our boundary header.

        $header[] = 'Authorization: WRAP access_token="'.$this->accesstoken.'"';
        $header[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$BOUNDARY;
        print_r($BODY);         
        $ch = curl_init();              
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->baseAddress);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');  // tell curl you want to post something
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $BODY); // define what you want to post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION , CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);     
        $output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($output, 0, $header_size);
        $this->response = substr($output, $header_size);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $this->responsecode = $info['http_code'];           
        curl_close ($ch); // close curl
```

I also tried to send file by creating object. In this case it gives below error.

```
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath('testcp.txt'),'text/plain');
        $uploadPost = array (
            'file' => $cfile
         );         
        $eol = "\r\n";
        $BOUNDARY = md5(time());
        $BODY=""; //init my curl body
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY. $eol; //start param header    

        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY. $eol; // start 2nd param,
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY .'--' . $eol. $eol; // we close the param and the post width "--" and 2 $eol at the end of our boundary header.

            $header[] = 'Authorization: WRAP access_token="'.$this->accesstoken.'"';
            $header[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$BOUNDARY;
            print_r($BODY);
            //ECHO $this->accesstoken;EXIT;
            $ch = curl_init();  
            //echo $this->baseAddress;exit;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->baseAddress);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');  // tell curl you want to post something
    //      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($data)); // define what you want to post
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $uploadPost); // define what you want to post
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION , CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);     

            $output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
            echo 'OUTPUT ---';print_r($output);exit;        
            curl_close ($ch);
```

Error :

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
>   complete.

Comment: Seriously, don't bother with Curl.  Get [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) and use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#uploading-data) - Otherwise use guzzle anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array("body" => $BODY)));

Or at least URL-encode $BODY;